# Correct JS parse of URL transmitted via JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Here's a simplified PHP side of my ajax context:

```
// in a for loop
    $text = "/home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt"
    // $text_encoded = urlencode($text);
    // $text_encoded = preg_replace("/(\-)/", "%2D", $text_encoded);
    $text_encoded = "%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE%2DHDD%2D100%2Fy.txt"
    $structure[$i] = $text_encoded;

echo json_encode($structure);
```

And here is the JS side:

```
request.onload = function()
{
    var cleanedText = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    alert(cleanedText);
};
```

That throws the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

If I substitute `JSON.parse(this.responseText)` with `decodeURI(this.responseText)`, I get `cleanedText` equal to

> /home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt
>   ["%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE-HDD-100%2Fy.txt"]

which I dislike, since an hypotetic `for` loop on `cleanedText` would treat every element of that variable (correctly) as a character, while I'd obviously like to get elements as whole URLs.

A possible, dirty workaround is to set up some *regex* on `cleanedText` to recover every URL, but I'm wondering if there would be a much cleaner way.

Comment: It'd be helpful it you could post the JSON output from the PHP file, but my first guess would be that there's some other character output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w3re's comment has to be correct. You must have malformed JSON. We can show this by taking the output you do get from `decodeURI`, running it back through `encodeURI` to get what must therefore be your original string from PHP, and then trying `JSON.parse` on it. We get an error:

```
JSON.parse(encodeURI('/home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt ["%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE-HDD-100%2Fy.txt"]'))
(program):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

That error is from Chrome, but the `:1` is saying 'line 1' and the `/` is at column 1, so I think that's the error you're seeing.

Basically, this string is not valid JSON, because of the all the stuff at the start which is not wrapped in quotes.

However, for example, this will work, if you put it all in quotes and escape the existing ones:

```
JSON.parse('"/home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt \\"%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE-HDD-100%2Fy.txt\\""')
```

or using an array:

```
JSON.parse('["/home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt", "%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE-HDD-100%2Fy.txt"]')
```

or an object:

```
JSON.parse('{"/home/ubuntu/CANE-HDD-100/y.txt": "%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2FCANE-HDD-100%2Fy.txt"}')
```

so something must be going awry in your PHP or JavaScript in and amongst your JSON encoding and decoding. To help further, I'd need to see more of your code.